# The proof of $\log(1+x) < x.$

Tags: inequality, taylor-expansion

I want to prove $\log(1+x) < x.$

Of course, I can prove this by letting $f(x):= x - \log(1+x),$ and calculating $f'(x)$, ... .

But I wonder if I can prove this using Maclaurin's expansion.

$\log(1+x)=x-\dfrac{1}{2}x^2+\dfrac{1}{3} x^3-\cdots.$

The right-hand side includes the term "$x$" so it seems that I can use this equality in order to prove $\log(1+x) < x$, but I cannot.

I would like you to give me some ideas.

Comment: Take care : the expansion is valif for $|x|<1$

Comment: Also: you'd like to say that the sum of the alternating series (i.e., everything starting with the $x^2$ term) has the same sign as the first term of the series...but that only works if it's actually *alternating*; if $x < 0$, it's not.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3275429/textshow-that-log1x-le-x-quad-forall-x-in-0-infty?noredirect=1)

Comment: I believe the inequality is not true in general.

Comment: For which $x$ do you consider this inequality? For real positive numbers of complex numbers?

Answer (score 4):

Since you talk about series expansions, one could exponentiate the inequality (the exponential function is monotonically increasing, so this is equivalent to the original inequality) to obtain $e^x > 1 + x$, which is easy to prove with the series expansion of the exponential function: we have $$e^x = 1 + x + \underbrace{x^2 + \ldots}_{> 0} > 1 + x$$ for all $x > 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $0<x<1$, then if we let $a_k(x) = (-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k}x^k$ we see that
$$\log (1+x)-x = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}a_k(x).$$

Now note that in the specified interval we have that $|a_k(x)|>|a_{k+1}(x)|$ and that $\mathrm{sgn}\, a_k(x) = -\mathrm{sgn}\, a_{k+1}(x)$ so that the sum is alternating. These two properties implies that $a_{2k}(x)+a_{2k+1}(x)<0$ and therefore
$$\log(1+x)-x= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}a_k(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\underbrace{a_{2k}(x)+a_{2k+1}(x)}_{<0}<0$$

Answer (score 2):

For me the simplest proof is to look for the minimum value of $$f(x)=x- \log (1+x)$$
$$f'(x)=1-\frac 1{1+x} \qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x)=\frac 1{x^2} \quad > 0~~\forall x$$  So the extremum is at $x=0$ and the second derivative test shows that this is a minimum. So, in real domain, $\forall x$
$$x \geq \log(1+x).$$

Comment: Isn't that already mentioned in the question? *“I can prove this by letting $f(x):=x- \text{log} (1+x),$ and calculating $f'(x), $ ...”*

Comment: @MartinR. If $\cdots$ means $f''(x) +\text{second derivative test}$, yes.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of natural log in [How can we come up with the definition of natural logarithm?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2678805/290189) allows a proof without words.

[image: graph of natural log]
[interactive graph made from Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0tcgomivns)

\begin{align}
\mathrm{LHS} &:= \int_1^{1+x} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t} = \text{area under the curve} \\
\mathrm{RHS} &= x = \text{area of the rectangle}
\end{align}

The curve $y = 1/x$ is below $y = 1$ on $x \ge 1$.

Exercise: complete this proof for the case $x \in (-1,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

If you accept (otherwise this can easily be proved) that $\log ()$ is a concave function, then it suffices to show (cf. Jensen) that $x$ is a tangent to $\log(1+x)$. But this is obvious: $x$ and $\log(1+x)$ touch at $x=0$ and have the same slope ($1$) there.

Answer (score 0):

A "proof without words" :[image] $\forall x>-1, x\neq 0, \log(1+x)<x.$